# Build a user's profile directory on creation in batch

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

I have a batch script that I use when I set up new Windows 7 PCs that creates a user based on a variable, creates a folder on their desktop, then shares it:

> @echo off
>
> SET /p unitnumber="Enter unit number: "
>
> net user unit%unitnumber% password /add /expire:never
>
> MD "C:/Users/unit%unitnumber%/Desktop/Accounting #%unitnumber%"
>
> runas /user:administrator "net share "Accounting#%unitnumber%"="C:/Users/unit%unitnumber%/Desktop/Accounting#%unitnumber""

I discovered that the share that is created is overwritten when the newly created user first logs on, because Windows creates builds their profile directory at that time.

Is there any way to initiate a build of a user's profile directory in the batch file just after creating the it? The only thing that looks useful is the `/homedir:pathname` switch for the `net user` command, but I believe that option assumes the directory already exists.

I'd be willing to use whatever to get this done as long as I can incorporate/launch it from the batch.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new user makes a login for the first time usually the directory `c:\Users\Default` is copied to the directory with the name of the user. I think that must be enough to build into your batch script.

Comment: You're right, just watched my Windows installation from linux and didn't recognis that there are multiple symlinks to the directory. On my installation I got `Documents and Settings` and `Dokumente und Einstellungen` as it is called on a german installation. And `Default User` is a symlink to `Default`. Just an old habbit from Windows XP times...