# Create a new user's profile from the command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, user-profiles

I am creating an installation script that should create a few users, and set some registry settings for them. In order to use reg.exe to modify their registry, I need to have the location of their ntuser.dat, normally residing in the users' home directories.

The home directories are only created during the users' first login, which is a little late for my batch file. I don't wish to have to log into each user.

Is there a way to create the home directories without logging into the users?
I assume it would involve copying the "\Users\Default" directory, but what else needs to be done?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/663357/build-a-users-profile-directory-on-creation-in-batch) is similar to mine, but does not refer to the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store default user-settings for new users the registry-key `HKEY_USERS -> .DEFAULT` was made.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/chad/archive/2012/04/25/tip-49-how-do-you-set-default-user-profile-registry-settings.aspx

But this approach works for all users logged in from the point of change.

If you want to add registry-entries for particular users of your (Active Directory-)Domain then you should have a look at `Group Policies` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy

Comment: Thanks! Modifying the default profile could work for our scenario. I am unsure if the .DEFAULT Key actually would work. The link you provide does not use it, but loads the Default Hive manually. We are not in a Domain, so we can't use Group Policies. I'd rather leave the default profile unchanged, so I'll wait a little longer for other answers. =)

Answer (score 0):

i think what you need might be `/homedir` and `/profilepath` switches of [`net user`](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/251394) command, you can find full help on syntax in `net help user` output

ps:

you can also try making user directories using `mkdir` before creating accounts and then add users